# Link OpenMPI against libc++

Tags: opensuse, libraries, linker, mpi

I'm running OpenSUSE 13.2 and for various reasons, a project I'm working on requires OpenMPI to be linked against `libc++` rather than `libstd++`.

I've already tried setting the following environment variables:

```
CXX <path>/llvm-3.8/bin/clang++
CC <path>/llvm-3.8/bin/clang
OMPI_CC <path>/llvm-3.8/bin/clang
OMPI_CXX <path>/llvm-3.8/bin/clang++
```

But whilst this does compile using clang, it still links to `libstdc++` as confirmed from the following commands run on various executables in the openmpi bin folder:

```
openmpi-1.10.2/bin > ldd vtc++
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffc9f0ed000)
        libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007ffb1f2cd000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007ffb1efcb000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007ffb1edb4000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007ffb1ea0d000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007ffb1f611000)
```

And:

```
openmpi-1.10.2/bin > objdump -x vtc++ | grep NEEDED
  NEEDED               libstdc++.so.6
  NEEDED               libm.so.6
  NEEDED               libgcc_s.so.1
  NEEDED               libc.so.6
```

Any advice greatly appreciated.

Comment: There's a `-stdlib=...` argument you need to pass.

Comment: I mean the OpenMPI libraries themselves need to be built against libc++, not the program I write using OpenMPI?

Comment: Everything needs to be built with the same standard library (including all static and shared libs), otherwise you get undefined behavior with really nasty to debug issues (ODR violations all over the place)

Comment: Why did you delete your identical question that you asked on SO in parallel to UNIX.SE where I explained everything to you in the comments?

Comment: @Zulan this was migrated here and they are identical so I had to delete one. I don't mean to be rude but your explanations didn't actually answer my question as I don't believe you understood fully what I was asking. As neither of the questions had suitable comments / answers it didn't really matter which one I chose.

Comment: I'll copy and paste your most relevant comment from that page though for continuity:

"Like with most autotools projects, you can set CC, CXX and LDFLAGS for the configure. But use only clang, not the relative path, and set the PATH accordingly. This is all perfectly documented in the [OpenMPI FAQ](https://www.open-mpi.org/faq/?category=all#build-compilers)"

However like I said, I've already done all of that (as the question states) and it still didn't do what I needed/expected - hence the question here.

Comment: First, it is [not ok to cross-post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/317725). Second, whether you meant it or not, it is rude to delete a question where someone has spent time attempting to help you.

Comment: Apologies for cross posting, this has obviously been sorted now. I've pasted your comment from the deleted question above; time not wasted. Let's not argue. Is there any more information I can give that will further clarify my issue or what I've tried?

Comment: You need to pass `-stdlib=...` to clang. I'd assume for compilation *and* linking. And the [FAQ explains, "Can I pass specific flags to the compilers / linker used to build Open MPI?"](https://www.open-mpi.org/faq/?category=all#build-compiler-flags)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Zulan and @Mat for their help.

My issue was that whilst I had set the correct compiler, I had not passed it the `-stdlib=c++` flag. To do this with an OpenMPI build in particular using `configure`, you must set the `CFLAGS` and `CXXFLAGS` environment variables to contain `-stdlib=libc++`. I did this through a module file with `prepend-path`.